# Will Canadian ISPs be affected by US Broadband Privacy removals?

Tags: privacy, vpn, isp

The US Senate just voted 50/48 to permanently eliminate all privacy rules for ISPs. If it passes the House, then they can sell US consumer information to paying companies.

Will Canadian ISPs, like Shaw or Telus, be affected, or should Canadians only be concerned with US-based servers? Would a VPN be a good investment in these trying times?

The House version of this bill is called H.J.Res 86

Comment: no, Canada is not subject to US law.

Comment: Not currently but given the way Canada and US exchange law enforcement tactics and data there is a chance that similar legislation may be proposed and there is a possibility it may also be enacted. I would suspect they are watching closely to see how this plays out in the US. Canada is also slightly more cognizant of its citizen's freedoms so there is a chance they won't go this route at all.